# REST GET array - how to handle errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

In my application, I have a React front end, Express server connected to a MongoDB. My users are members of groups. Each group has a small dashboard. I want to have a single web page that displays a dashboard for each group the user is a member of.

I was thinking I would submit a GET request with parameters for each group, to return an array of groups.

My question is: what is the best way to do authorization here? Should I return an array that contains a mix of found records and unauthorized errors, or should I just send an HTTP 403 for the entire request if the user is unauthorized for one (or more) of the groups they’ve requested? Or, am I thinking about this all wrong and should be sending individual GET requests for each group dashboard (I feel like this is very inefficient)?

If anyone has references for more information in these types of design practices I’d be happy to have them as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition will be to go with your latter approach, although it depends a bit on how tough your security posture is. It's easy to introduce bugs in 'mixed authorisation' code, and create a target for vulnerability extraction. It's better to send a 403 for the whole result. Think about it this way - the user's request generated a query that asks for unauthorised data - it doesn't matter if it's "partially" authorised.

Google's Zanzibar paper: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/atc19-pang.pdf tries to answer many authorisation questions in Google's scale and context, at a conceptual level.

Comment: Thanks, that practice makes sense to me. Haven't had any input, so marking as correct!